# PHP interactive shell and NO newline with echo

Tags: php, shell

I have compiled PHP with the --with-readline option and I got the interactive shell, but I have an annoying problem, when I echo something the echo doesn't print a newline character I mean:

```
****@****-PC ~ $ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > echo 1+2;
3php > echo "Hello World!";
Hello World!php >
```

Where is the problem? How can I resolve it? 
Because watching [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) it prints a newline.

Comment: there is no linebreak after the string

Comment: This is a known bug for some versions of PHP ( https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55496 ) . What version are you running if you run `php -v` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to force the interactive mode to always output a newline, you can declare it as such on startup:

```
php -dcli.prompt="\nphp> " -a
```

(Or rather adapt the php.ini)

Comment: What exactly -dcli.prompt do?

Comment: @HaRsH - this is a workaround if the version of PHP is buggy and doesn't automatically force the prompt onto a newline. For the record, the OP is describing a bug that is *not* expected behavior and the interactive shell is not designed to force the user to manually add a newline for any single line output.

Comment: How can I edit `php.ini`? With `dcli.prompt="\nphp> " -a`? I try `locate php.ini`. Should I try `/etc/php5/php.ini`?